# How can I solve this logical and algorithm problem?

Tags: algorithm, logic

On a mountain, there are honest monkeys and unreliable monkeys. The honest monkeys always tell the truth while the unreliable monkeys may lie or may tell the truth. The monkeys themselves can tell who is honest and who is unreliable, but an outsider can’t tell the difference.
Suppose that there are n monkeys on the mountain, and there are strictly more than n/2 honest monkeys. Could you give an algorithm to find out all honest monkeys by asking them whether others are honest?

I have considered the problem for some time and tried some search engines but still got no idea.

Comment: Could you please add the source of the problem, so we can see that it's not part of a live competition?

Comment: *an outsider can’t tell the difference* What does it mean? What is an outsider? An unreliable monkey? I guess you have some efficiency constraints. If not, there seems to be an obvious O(n^2) algorithm, ... if I understand tje problem well.

Comment: The problem was asked by my classmate. I think it upgrades from an old problem that the honest monkeys always tell the truth while the unreliable monkeys always lie.

Comment: Suppose that you are the outsider and have to find out all honest monkeys.

Comment: If you don't have efficiency constraints, just ask to every monkey who are the reliable ones and who are not. Each monkey that will receive a positive score is reliable.

Comment: Oh,it is a good idea! I can asked other monkeys whether the first monkey is reliable. If honest >n/2,it must be honest. If unreliable >n/2,it must be unreliable. When I find the first honest monkey, I can ask it whether others are honest. But this method will  reach O(n^2) when I continuously find out unreliable monkeys. Is there an algorithm that can reach O(n)?

Comment: @SNORLAX Are you looking for expected performance or worst case performance?

Comment: Now I wonder if my algotithm can reach O(n) in worse case

Comment: Can you ask the monkeys how many in the group are honest? Or alternatively, given two subgroups, which group has more of the honest monkeys in it?

Comment: of course not.You can only one monkey whether another is honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stimulated by comment! I can asked other monkeys whether the first monkey is reliable. If honest >n/2,it must be honest. If unreliable >n/2,it must be unreliable. When I find the first honest monkey, I can ask it whether others are honest. But this method will reach O(n^2) when I continuously find out unreliable monkeys. Is there an algorithm that can reach O(n)?

Comment: Since more than half the monkeys are reliable, if you choose the monkeys at random, then you should expect to find an honest monkey quickly. So you can expect the algorithm to be linear, although when you're terribly unlucky it can be quadratic.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if there is a better algorigthm